# why append tab to String in csv will give me an extra space in the tail

Tags: java, string, excel, csv, format

I'd like to write to a CSV file some data.

I append \t to all the strings to keep all the leading zeros.

but it will append a space in the tail of each column in excel. why?

Is there any way to get rid of that space?

(I tried using single quote instead of tab but it will show that quote in excel which I don't want)

Comment: When you say it will show the quote do you mean when you re-open the file in excel? (instead of say notepad)

Comment: @NickSlash, yeah, I'm exporting data into csv from java web app. the user will open this file in excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your CSV file has a fixed layout then the simplest method is probably to create a macro to automate the text import wizard.

Doing this you wont need to add any extra characters to qualify text values in your csv file.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\Users\Example\test.csv", Origin _
        :=65001, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
        xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), _
        Array(2, 2), Array(3, 2)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End Sub
```

The above code loads a 3 column csv file, and sets each column to be `Text` instead of `General`.

If you have control over the generation of the CSV file you might want to encapsulate your values with leading zeros in quotes (either single or double) and specify this in the wizard when recording the macro.

Comment: I give up and use workbook to generate excel files, thanks for help anyway